# Can't control width of sr-speedbar

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs with sr-speedbar, but can't control its width. When I resize the emacs window, the sr-speedbar always expands with it. I have tried this both with xemacs and emacs.

My .emacs file below:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                     ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
(setq c-default-style "linux"
          c-basic-offset 4)
(iswitchb-mode 1)
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(require 'ecb)
(setq stack-trace-on-error t)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
;(defun toggle-fullscreen ()
;  (interactive)    
;  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
;                '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0))
;  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
;                '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0))
;)
;(toggle-fullscreen)
(require 'sr-speedbar)
(setq 
   sr-speedbar-right-side nil
   sr-speedbar-width-x 10
   sr-speedbar-width-console 10
   sr-speedbar-max-width 10
   sr-speedbar-delete-windows t)
(sr-speedbar-open)
(put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
;; Single char cursor movement. (assuming you are on qwerty)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-l") 'forward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-i") 'previous-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-k") 'next-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") 'set-mark-command)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote         ("d63e19a84fef5fa0341fa68814200749408ad4a321b6d9f30efc117aeaf68a2e" default)))
 '(ecb-options-version "2.40"))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It consumes variables at load time, not when open.

The sr-speedbar-width-* should be set before the script loaded.

Comment: Please clarify your answer, as it can be misinterpreted.  Wouldn't setting a variable prior to loading a library be overridden by the library once it loads?  For example:  A library contains a variable named "xyz".  If the user sets the value of "xyz" before the library loads, then loading the library will undo the prior setting.  Whereas loading the library first and then setting "xyz" will permit the latter setting to remain in effect.

Comment: It is about sr-speedbar library and variables sr-speedbar-width-x and sr-speedbar-width-console.
The sr-speedbar uses the variables when loading and initializing.
When it is already loaded with require or load-library, changing the variables can not take any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because the variables `sr-speedbar-width-x` and `sr-speedbar-width-console` do not exist any more. They have been removed from the code on 03 Aug 2014. See here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/sr-speedbar.el

The information that you probably found on https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar is outdated.

There is only one variable `sr-speedbar-width`

The variable is "consumed" when `sr-speedbar-open` is called. The user can define the variable before or after loading the library. This is due to the behaviour of the Emacs Lisp special form `defvar` (line 364), which does not overwrite the variable. For more information on this see here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html